# Java substring from right-hand direction, until a specific character

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to select specific substring from the input string:

```
String i = "example/test/foo-foo";
```

How to get only the substring `foo-foo` as a new string?

Expected output:

```
String newString = "foo-foo";
```

Comment: Did you have any look at the methods that `String` provides?

Comment: int index = i.lastIndexOf("/");
String name= i.substring(index + 1);

Comment: `String i = "example/test/foo-foo";
    String[] temp = i.split("/");
    System.out.println(temp[temp.length-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is through a utility class since we can reuse the code with this approach. Furthermore some corner cases can be handled to avoid runtime exceptions.

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static final String EMPTY = "";

    public static String substringAfterLast(String str, String separator) {
        if (isEmpty(str)) {
            return str;
        }
        if (isEmpty(separator)) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        int pos = str.lastIndexOf(separator);
        if (pos == -1 || pos == (str.length() - separator.length())) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        return str.substring(pos + separator.length());
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    }
}
```

Then create your `newString` using,

`String newString = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(i, "/");`

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to solve that. For example via regex search/replace or the substring methods of class String.

Regex approach:

```
Optional<String> resultA = Optional.of(string.replaceAll("^.*/([^/]+)$", "$1"));
```

Substring approach:

```
int start = string.lastIndexOf('/');
Optional<String> resultB = Optional.of(start > 0 && start + 1 < string.length() ? string.substring(start) : null);
```

There are plenty of more elaborate solutions for this problem on stackoverflow btw., so you might be better off with a thorough stackoverflow search.